# How to prevent C++ string stream from reading double into int?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I want to write a function that reads an integer from a string and throws errors when encountering invalid inputs. Invalid inputs include non-digit and non-integer inputs. The following function detects non-digit inputs as invalid input but does not handle double inputs. Since reading into int will just grab digits and when it reaches "." it stops reading. So if the user passes "1.5" the function below will return "1" but I am expecting an error. How can I handle double inputs?

```
int ReadInt(const std::string& line) {
    int entry{};
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> entry;
    if (iss.fail()) { 
        // Throw Unexpected Input Exception
    }
    return entry;
}
```

Comment: [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) making sure to use the output parameter `pos` to see how much the string it was able to convert into an int

Comment: If you're being forced to use older compilers or standards, you can get similar functionality from C's [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I handle double inputs?

You can check whether the entire input was consumed. If it wasn't, then the input contained something more than just an integer. If you don't want to accept such input, then treat such input as invalid and handle it accordingly (throw exception, ask input again, etc.)